# Can't trigger Bazel remote caching

Tags: bazel

I'm trying set up Bazel remote caching with no success so far. The problem I'm having is that Bazel does not seem to read/write to cache at all.

Steps I took:

- Boot up a VM running Linux
- Install Bazel 6.2.1 using Bazelisk
- Clone this repo https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel
- Run `bazel build examples/py_native:bin --disk_cache=~/.cache/bazel_disk`, nothing is created inside `~/.cache/bazel_disk`
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeSAe.png)
- Run `bazel build examples/shell:bin --remote_cache=https://storage.googleapis.com/dsp-bazel-cache`, nothing is created inside the GCS bucket
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnrUC.pngg)

I already run `bazel clean` beforehand.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/867OD.png)

I'm trying to understand what happened and where I can check logs to troubleshoot here. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Building" a simple Python binary does not require much work. Therefore, there isn't anything interesting to cache. Try out something more heavyweight like C++, Java, or running a test.

Also, keep in mind that if the output tree is already up to date from a previous build, Bazel will not have to build anything and therefore not populate the cache. Run `bazel clean` to remove the output tree.

Comment: My project is much more complex, I just use the example as a quick test. But in any case, I thought the caching should work and create something. That's confusing me. Is there a log that shows the caching actually gets triggered.

Comment: Maybe you need to run `bazel clean`?

Comment: I for sure ran `bazel clean` beforehand. I added a new screenshot to my original post.

Comment: Building the simple python binary is never going to put anything in the cache.